# Убрать пространство в меню при переходе на HTML5

Tags: html, css

Есть html код:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background:url(http://www.vizitka-primerius.com/i.gif);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  color: #003596;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
}

p {
    margin-top: 5px; /* Отступ сверху */
    margin-bottom: 5px; /* Отступ снизу */
   }



div.footer{padding-left: 40px; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px;}

div.first{padding-left: 40px; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; text-align: justify;}
div.second{padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; text-align: justify;}
div.third{padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 40px; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; text-align: justify;}

div.divmenu{padding-left: 40px;}
table tr.authors{background-color: #e7effa; width: 100%;}
table tr.menu{background-color: #e7effa; width: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block;}

.table-c{
  width: 100%; border: 0px; height: 100%; min-width: 780px; overflow: hidden; border-spacing: 0px;
}
.table-c td{
  padding: 0px;
}
nav {
  margin: 0px; 
}

nav ul ul {
  display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

nav ul {
  background: #e7effa; 
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-table;

}

nav ul:after {
  content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background: #426ed2;
}

nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block; padding: 20px 30px;
  color: #003596; text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul ul {
  background: #426ed2; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
  position: absolute; top: 100%;
}

nav ul ul li {
  float: none; 
  position: relative;
}

nav ul ul li a {
  padding: 20px 30px;
  color: #fff;
} 

nav ul ul li a:hover {
  background: #003596;
}

nav ul ul ul {
  position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
}
```

```html
<table class=table-c>
  <tr class=menu><td>
  <div class=divmenu>
<nav style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
  <ul style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
    <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Продукция</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Группа 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Группа 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Группа 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Группа 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Группа 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Группа 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Группа 3</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Подгруппа 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подгруппа 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Оптовые Продажи</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>    
</div>
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

В итоге получаем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как убрать по всему меню голубое горизонтальное пространство в несколько пикселей?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В nav ul убрать display: inline-table

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background:url(http://www.vizitka-primerius.com/i.gif);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  color: #003596;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
}

p {
    margin-top: 5px; /* Отступ сверху */
    margin-bottom: 5px; /* Отступ снизу */
   }



div.footer{padding-left: 40px; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px;}

div.first{padding-left: 40px; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; text-align: justify;}
div.second{padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; text-align: justify;}
div.third{padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 40px; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; text-align: justify;}

div.divmenu{padding-left: 40px;}
table tr.authors{background-color: #e7effa; width: 100%;}
table tr.menu{background-color: #e7effa; width: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block;}

.table-c{
  width: 100%; border: 0px; height: 100%; min-width: 780px; overflow: hidden; border-spacing: 0px;
}
.table-c td{
  padding: 0px;
}
nav {
  margin: 0px; 
}

nav ul ul {
  display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

nav ul {
  background: #e7effa; 
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul:after {
  content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background: #426ed2;
}

nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block; padding: 20px 30px;
  color: #003596; text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul ul {
  background: #426ed2; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
  position: absolute; top: 100%;
}

nav ul ul li {
  float: none; 
  position: relative;
}

nav ul ul li a {
  padding: 20px 30px;
  color: #fff;
} 

nav ul ul li a:hover {
  background: #003596;
}

nav ul ul ul {
  position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
}
```

```html
<table class=table-c>
  <tr class=menu><td>
  <div class=divmenu>
<nav style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
  <ul style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
    <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Продукция</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Группа 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Группа 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Группа 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Группа 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Группа 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Группа 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Группа 3</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Подгруппа 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подгруппа 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Оптовые Продажи</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>    
</div>
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: работает, что делает этот тег?

Comment: Не понял вопроса

Comment: inline-table обтекает внутренние элементы

Comment: не знаю как поменяется логика меню, в предыдущем ответе субменю перестало работать...

Comment: всего кода нету, а там есть ньюансы, усли убрать <!DOCTYPE html> то все правильно отображается, ну и еще видно что в таблице рисуется нижний отступ в 2px